# XMonad: layout with n columns

Tags: xmonad

I'm looking for an XMonad layout which allows to add and remove columns.

As an example:

```
+-----+-----+
|     |  2  |
|  1  +-----+
|     |  3  |
+-----+-----+
```

By adding a new column, the windows would arrange as follows:

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

Does such a layout exist?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the second example sounds like it could be accomplished with: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Layout-MultiColumns.html

Comment: Thanks! Do you know whether it is possible to dynamically add new columns using this extension (without re-configuring and restarting XMonad)?

Comment: Possibly the layout supports this - you'd have to look at the source code. Alternatively you could create multiple 'layout's with incremental columns set - but it would be a bit of a hacky approach.